# shared_pointer unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

There is piece of code:

A.cpp

```
class MySomeClass: public SomeClass
{
   public: 
   void specificMethod();
}

class A
{
    public:
    A::A();

    std::shared_ptr< B > m_bObject;
    std::shared_ptr< MySomeClass > m_argument;
}

A::A()
{
    m_argument= std::make_shared< MySomeClass >();
    m_bObject = std::make_shared< B >( m_argument);
}
```

B.cpp

```
B::B(const std::shared_ptr< SomeClass >& smartOne):m_smartOne(smartOne)
{}

B::someMethod()
{
    m_smartOne->specificMethod();
}
```

B.h

```
class B
{
public:
    B(const std::shared_ptr< SomeClass >& smarOne);
    void someMethod();

private:
    const std::shared_ptr< SomeClass >& m_smartOne;
};
```

Problem is when I call `m_bObject->someMethod()` there is a core dump because `m_smartOne` is not a `MySomeClass` but `SomeClass`.
Why? Is it scope problem, ownership problem, other?
I've recieved code of `B` class and can't change it.

Comment: `const std::shared_ptr< SomeClass >& m_smartOne;` What craziness is this?

Comment: @StoryTeller Not really. I see minimal benefit over storing a `shared_ptr` by value, and plenty of headaches.

Comment: I've noticed this construction, but I am new with shared pointers and I dont know why this is bad.

Comment: @T.C. - I deleted my comment when I realized what you were referring to. Thought it was about the constructor accepting it by reference, which *could* make sense. The member is pure nonsense, like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `std::make_shared<B>(m_argument)` constructs the `B` object, it will create a temporary `shared_ptr<SomeClass>` object from `m_argument`, which is of the type `shared_ptr<MySomeClass>`. A reference to that temporary is passed to `B`'s constructor, which stores a reference that immediately became dangling as the temporary object is destroyed after the constructor call completes.

The result of using a dangling reference is, of course, undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

If you can't touch `B`, then the best you can do is probably to have `A` store a `shared_ptr<SomeClass>` member so that no temporary is created. But even then `A` will effectively store a reference into itself, which means that the default copy/move constructors and assignment operators will all do the wrong thing. That's a giant can of worms.

Comment: But m_argument is an member and I expect it will be available during class life. As I understand during make_shared<B> is created ANOTHER temporary shared_ptr based on m_argument. Am I right?

Comment: If you can't touch B you should rather run away quickly.

Comment: @rainbow `m_argument` is of type `shared_ptr<MySomeClass>`, `B`'s constructor wants a `shared_ptr<SomeClass> const&`, so you need to create a temporary `shared_ptr<SomeClass>` from `m_argument`.

Comment: @rainbow No, `static_pointer_cast` will also create a temporary.

Comment: @rainbow If `A` owns `B`, then you should have a `unique_ptr<B>` instead of a `shared_ptr<B>`, and you should simply store a `SomeClass &` or `SomeClass *` in `B`.